# Restructuring JSON Response in Angular 2+

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm currently receiving a web api JSON response that is heavily nested and I want to restructure it plucking out only the data I need and making it more simple.

How would I do this in Angular 2+/Typescript?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Say I have something like this:

```
"O1": {
    "P1": "Something",
    "A1": [{
       "P2": "Something",
       "A2": [{
         "P3": "Something"
        }]
    }]
    "P4": "Something"
}
```

and I want to restructure it to this :

```
"O1": {
    "P1": "Something",
    "P2": "Something",
    "P3": "Something"
}
```

Can I rebuild the model in a class in the constructor? If so, I haven't been able to find anything online as of yet.

Let me know if I need to provide any further info.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, you want all primitive values and their respective keys from the object?

Comment: Not all of them, just specific values - some deeply nested and other are not.

Answer (score 0):

Found this snippet in github:
https://gist.github.com/penguinboy/762197

```
var flattenObject = function(ob) {
    var toReturn = {};

    for (var i in ob) {
        if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

        if ((typeof ob[i]) == 'object') {
            var flatObject = flattenObject(ob[i]);
            for (var x in flatObject) {
                if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;

                toReturn[i + '.' + x] = flatObject[x];
            }
        } else {
            toReturn[i] = ob[i];
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hamid, this has indeed flattened the json but the reponse im getting atm is very complex and there are hundreds of objects inside arrays etc so I need to be specific on what value I get in the flattened data. Is there a way to choose what properties to include in the new object?

Answer (score 0):

Let's flatten the initial object using the [snippet which was proposed](https://gist.github.com/penguinboy/762197). And then we can filter those properties which we need to include in the final object:

```
 function filterObj(obj: any, propsForFilter: string[]) {
  const result = {};
  for (let prop in obj) {
    const filteredProp = propsForFilter.find(p => prop.includes(p));
    if (filteredProp) {
      result[filteredProp] = obj[prop];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
const flattened = flattenObject(obj);
console.log(flattened, filterObj(flattened, ['P1', 'P2']));
```

This method `filterObj` accepts the array of properties in order to include them in the final result. Hope this will be helpful for you.